# Magento 2 cron notaction - comma separated values

Tags: xml, cron, magento2

I'm trying to set up a cron job to run on **last Sunday of each month at 4:00PM**.

I came up with this:

https://crontab.guru/#00_16_*/25,*/26,*/27,*/28,*/29,*/30,*/31_*_7

```
00 16 */25,*/26,*/27,*/28,*/29,*/30,*/31 * 7
```

I've put this into crontab.xml (which was running before with */1 * * * *)

```
<group id="default">
   <job instance="Company\DeleteOldProducts\Cron\DeleteOldProducts" method="execute" name="delete_old_products">
    <schedule>00 16 */25,*/26,*/27,*/28,*/29,*/30,*/31 * 7</schedule>
   </job>
</group>
```

This, for some reason does not generate the cron tasks.

Does Magento 2 accept this comma separated notation?

I've looked around and don't see any errors in exception.log or system.log or debug.log.

Any ideas?

Comment: Slightly unrelated – your expression may not be quite right. I don't know what cron flavor you are using, but, for example on Debian cron, it will not trigger on 25 September 2022, but it will trigger twice on January 2023 (on the 1st and on the 29th).

Comment: @PēterisCaune Why would it trigger on January 1st, 2023? The script is not critical to run as it gets rid of small amount of products each time so even if it doubles up in a month it wont be critical.

Comment: `*/n` notation in the day-of-month field means "every n days starting from the 1st". For example, */5` would match on the 1st, 6th, 11th, 16th, ... And `*/25` matches on the 1st and the 26th. And, January 1st, 2023 is Sunday.

Comment: @PēterisCaune Thanks for letting me know! It looks like that's actually preferred for me as it will still perform the task in the next month even if it misses it in the current month. I actually prefer it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops, I just had to wait a bit longer. Looks like it accepted the job.

[cron job created - used a current date for testing that's why its May 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRgy8.png)